# how to validate mutliptle regx pattern at the same time at angular

Tags: regex, validation, angular, typescript

I have too many validations in my typescri pt as you will see in the snippet below .They are working fine. My first validation checks from 0 to 9 so when the user clicks 'A' or any non numeric character from alphabet it gives validation message that I described.

When I use another validation for 0 to 6 and describe another validation message for 0 -6 and press 'A' , it gives me error message for 0 - 6. How I can make it give exact validation message for it belongs to ?

Regards
Alper

TypeScript :

```
 constructor (private router: Router,private fbuilder: FormBuilder,private 
 http: Http,private titleService: Title){
 this.DIA11612Form = this.fbuilder.group({'input1': [this.formInput.input1,[
  Validators.required,
  Validators.pattern('[0-9]+'),
  Validators.pattern('[0-6]+'),
]});
}

 validationMessages = {'input1':{
   'required':'Required Area',
   'pattern':'Should be a non numeric character',
   'pattern':'Shout be between 0-6',
 }, };
```

Angular 2 Code HTML :

```
<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control"formControlName="input1" 
 id="input1"></td></tr>
<tr><td *ngIf="formErrors.input1" class="alert alert-danger"> {{ 
 formErrors.input1 }}</td></tr>
```

Comment: Just remove the 0-9 validation. The 0-6 validation is sufficient.

Comment: Hello Nizet. I have to show the user that you can not type a non numeric character . So the validation of 0-6 and non numeric needs to be different. Do you think that is possible ?

Comment: No they don't. If you tell the user that he may only type numbers from 0 to 6, then obviously, he can only type numbers. That's implied.

Comment: Thank you Nizet. Then I will show only the narrowest validation such like between 0 and 6